# jQuery Animation

Tags: jquery-animate

I am trying to recreate some effects similar to the div loading effects on this site i.e. there is no visible content when you load the page but upon clicking on a navigation link, it dynamically loads the divs.

http://worldofmerix.com

It is for a film studio website and I would like it to be interactive like this site. Does anyone know how I could achieve these effects with Javascript and/or jQuery?

Thanks for all the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you used jQuery before or looked at the docs? This is really quite simple using jQuery's built-in [animation effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) such as [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/). The site you've linked to doesn't dynamically load the content - it's all part of the same page and simply displayed and hidden as appropriate.

Here's a rough [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/4dNJQ/) showing how it works. Of course, you'd need to work out the styles and quirks in animations.